Running a program but preventing internet access with iptables
I'm attempting to use a .exe file via Wine and wanted to prevent the application from connecting to the internet. I was in the middle of using this very old guide when I got stuck on this step :

Step 4. Enable the new firewall settings you made above in step 3 by running the following command:

Code:
sudo /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables_no-internet_rule

but when running this command I get:

iptables v1.8.10 (nf_tables): owner: Bad value for "--gid-owner" option: "no-internet"

From my understanding from this forum iptables handles the "--gid-owner" command in a weird way and I do not have the know-how to configure the groups properly.
Has anyone had success with this method or a different one? Thanks in advance.
Running on Mint 22.

What you can try

Try to restart the computer

if this doesn't help

check what number the group has (cat /etc/group)
replace the group-name no-internet with the number you obtained IN your file /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables_no-internet_rule


Restarting did not help, but the result of cat /etc/group does not show my no-internet group existing so I guess that's a good place to start working on. I thought the point of the nano script was to add the group but I'm not sure.
